# QTableView issue with resizeEvent()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtableview

I have an object that inherits QTableView and overrides the resizeEvent() method to set the widths of the table columns to a percantage of the available space if the table as a whole is resized.

Code is as follows:

```cpp
void DDUTableView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* ev)
{
    int num_columns = NUM_ELEMENTS(COLUMN_WIDTHS);

    if (num_columns > 0) {
        int width = ev->size().width();
        int used_width = 0;

        // Set our widths to be a percentage of the available width
        for (int i = 0; i < num_columns - 1; i++) {
            int column_width = (width * COLUMN_WIDTHS[i]) / 100;
            this->setColumnWidth(i, column_width);
            used_width += column_width;
        }
    
        // Set our last column to the remaining width
        this->setColumnWidth(num_columns - 1, width - used_width);
    }

    // Call our base resizeEvent to handle the vertical resizing which 
    // we don't bother with here
    QTableView::resizeEvent(ev);
}
```

This all works fine until the user manually resizes one of the columns and stretches it beyond the viewport (bringing up the horizontal scrollbar). This then triggers my `resizeEvent()` call which resets the column widths to the percentage defaults.

I can overcome this issue by connecting to the `sectionResized()` signal on the table header and setting a timer running.  If the `resizeEvent()` is called whilst the timer is active then I don't recalculate the table widths.

Code below:

```cpp
connect(horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionResized(int, int, int)), this, SLOT(slotSectionResized(int, int, int)));

void DDUTableView::slotSectionResized(int /*logicalIndex*/, int /*oldSize*/, int /*newSize*/)
{
    timer_->start(500);
}


void DDUTableView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* ev)
{

if (timer_->isActive()) {
    return;
}
// etc
```

This works, but is messy.

Can I prevent the `resizeEvent()` from being called if the user manually adjusts the column headers beyond the scope of the viewport?  Alternatively, if not, is it possible to identify in the `resizeEvent()` whether this particular situation has occurred without having to set timers and the like?

Comment: Judging from your code, when user adjust col size will cause COLUMN_WIDTHS being written, correct? I am guess when user resize col, that says user expect one col has higher value in COLUMN_WIDTHS, which will have reduce some other col percent in COLUMN_WIDTHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if the scrollbar is visible worked for my scenario.

```
void DDUTableView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* ev)
{
    if (!horizontalScrollBar()->isVisible()) {

        int num_columns = NUM_ELEMENTS(COLUMN_WIDTHS);

        if (num_columns > 0) {
            int width = ev->size().width();
            int used_width = 0;

            // Set our widths to be a percentage of the available width
            for (int i = 0; i < num_columns - 1; i++) {
                int column_width = (width * COLUMN_WIDTHS[i]) / 100;
                this->setColumnWidth(i, column_width);
                used_width += column_width;
            }

            // Set our last column to the remaining width
            this->setColumnWidth(num_columns - 1, width - used_width);
        }
    }
    // Call our base resizeEvent to handle the vertical resizing which 
    // we don't bother with here
    QTableView::resizeEvent(ev);
```

}